# Facebook page get event data

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Im working on a website for an organization that has a facebook page and they create there events on that page. I want to make a graph call for the events and show them on there website but it does not work a smooth as i hoped.

I tried a few things and since api 2.3 i need to use the php sdk but to make graph calls i need an "App id" and a "App Secret" but it's a page and not an app. I found a few things to link an page to an app but is it possible to link a app to a (Organisation) page?

Comment: Create an app in the developer section, then you get your app id and app secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe said, create the app first at https://developers.facebook.com

Once you have created the app and set it up correctly, you can use the App ID and App Secret with the PHP SDK to access the Graph API.  The SDK requires App ID and App Secret, but Graph API calls themselves will require an access token.  You can either use a User Access Token (which the SDK will give you when you log in a user) or a Page Access Token (more info here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens )

Comment: Should i link the Page and the App some how? The page is already there and i cant find how i should link a new app to an existing page. User and Page Access Token does not work for me becouse they expire and i get an error if i use the App Access Token i think because the app and page are not linked.